# How to bring commits form another repository branch

Tags: git, repository, branch, commit, cherry-pick

So I want to bring only commits from another repository branch to my local branch. How can I do that or can i do that using cherry-pick?

So i tried merging two branches but it brought unrelated histories as well

Comment: What do you mean by "bring only commits"? All Git *has* is commits, really (well, and tags).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to have certain commits on your branch from another branch, then git cherry-pick is the way to go. This will pick the changes onto your branch, but be aware, that this will create a "new commit" (with the same source changes, but with different meta data like a different commit hash). So if you want to merge these two branches later, it will be show twice in your history.

Comment: So what should I do if I want to bring all the comments , but just commits nothing else